# How to make recyclerview show all item and can not scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am making an app to show all product in 1 view. I want the recyclerview show all item and can not scroll, just scroll parent view( ScrollView ). But problem is can not make height of recycler wrap all content.

[-->>I want like this](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/5074/pBClWI.png)

This is my code:

```
    <TextView
        android:text="Best seller:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#3f3f3f"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rv_bestSeller"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="New Product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#3f3f3f" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/rv_newProduct"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="All Product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#3f3f3f" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rv_allProduct" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[-->>But the space is so small](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/995/8qB4dP.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it's bad practice to do that , if you're doing that because of the headers use this library 
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

it will give you headers and you won't need a scrollview with lists inside.

if you really want to continue this way use NestedScrollView instead of the regular Scrollview

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

which will let you disable nested scrolling like you wanted

Comment: use setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: NestedScrollView and setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) fixed it. Thumbs up. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 15):

You should use `NestedScrollView` and `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` combined.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```